# FailedPreconditionError: GetNext() failed after loading a Tensorflow Saved_Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I built a dedicated class to build, train, save and then load my models. Saving is done with `tf.saved_model.simple_save` and then restored through `tf.saved_model.loader.load`.

Training and inference are done using the Dataset API. Everything works fine when using a trained model.

However if I restore a saved model, then inference breaks and throws this error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
>
> [[Node: datasets/cond/IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,?,30], [?,5]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I am certain that the iterator is initialized (the `print` is displayed as expected, see code below). May it have to do with the graphs variables belong to? Any other idea? I'm kind of stuck here

(simplified) **Code**:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
        with self.graph.as_default():
            model.features_data_ph = tf.Placeholder(...)
            model.labels_data_ph = tf.Placeholder(...)

    def build(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.logits = my_model(self.input_tensor)
            self.loss = my_loss(self.logits, self.labels_tensor)

    def train(self):
        my_training_procedure()

    def set_datasets(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            with tf.variable_scope('datasets'):
                self.dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.features_data_ph, self.labels_data_ph))
                self.iter = self.dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
                self.input_tensor, self.labels_tensor = self.iter.get_next

    def initialize_iterators(self, inference_data):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            feats = inference_data
            labs = np.zeros((len(feats), self.hp.num_classes))
            self.sess.run(self.iter.initializer,
                feed_dict={self.features_data_ph: feats,
                    self.labels_data_ph: labs})
            print('Iterator ready to infer')

    def infer(self, inference_data):
        self.initialize_iterators(inference_data)
        return sess.run(self.logits)

    def save(self, path):
        inputs = {"features_data_ph": self.features_data_ph,
            "labels_data_ph": self.labels_data_ph}
        outputs = {"logits": self.model.logits}
        tf.saved_model.simple_save(self.sess, path)

    @staticmethod
    def restore(path):
        model = Model()
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(model.sess, [tag_constants.SERVING], path)
        model.features_data_ph = model.graph.get_tensor_by_name("features_data_ph:0")
        model.labels_data_ph = model.graph.get_tensor_by_name("labels_data_ph:0")
        model.logits = model.graph.get_tensor_by_name("model/classifier/dense/BiasAdd:0")
        model.set_datasets()
        return model
```

**Failing routine**:

```
model1 = Model()
model1.build()
model1.train()
model1.save(model1_path)

...

model2 = Model.restore(model1_path)
model2.infer(some_numpy_array) # Error here, after print, at sess.run()
```

(Restoring the model works, tensor values match between original and restored models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the way I create the `Dataset`

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='dataset_init')
...
#retstoring
dataset_init_op = restored_graph.get_operation_by_name('dataset_init')
sess.run(
    dataset_init_op,
    feed_dict={...}
)
```

A working piece of code is available there -> https://vict0rsch.github.io/2018/05/17/restore-tf-model-dataset/

Comment: Is there way to get operation which is not given a name. I didn't gave name during training to make_initializer operation

Comment: look for the `make_initializer` op -> `dataset_init_op 
 = restored_graph.get_operation_by_name('make_initializer')`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and I believe the issue is that you're initializing a new Dataset object rather than initializing the Iterator that was saved with the model.

Try:

```
make_iter = model.get_operation_by_name("YOURPREFIX/MakeIterator")
sess.run(make_iter, feed_dict)
model.infer(some_numpy_array)
```

Comment: You just reminded me I had solved the issue and I should share it here. The idea is similar, I did lack the iterator's init op. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

a simple way: before the loop , add one line code:

```
tf.add_to_collection("saved_model_main_op",tf.group([train_iter], name='legacy_init_op'))
```

"saved_model_main_op" is fixed.

train_iter is the opt that initialize the iterator